# do notation and bind signature

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

I'm new to Haskell and functional programming and I was wondering why an example like this (the "nested loop") works:

```
do
  a <- [1, 2, 3]
  b <- [4, 5, 6]
  return $ a * 10 + b
```

Some of the stuff below is kind of pseudo-Haskell syntax, but I hope it illustrates my understanding.

**It's my understanding that it's turned into something like this**

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= \a -> 
          ([4, 5, 6] >>= \b -> 
                     return $ b * 10 + a)
```

**I think this expression**

```
[4, 5, 6] >>= \b -> return $ b * 10 + a
```

**Produces a list of partially applied functions**

```
[[40 + a], [50 + a], [60 + a]]
```

**Concatenated to**

```
[40 + a, 50 + a, 60 + a]
```

**For the last step, something looks like this**

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= \a -> [40 + a, 50 + a, 60 + a]
```

**Becomes**

```
[41, 51, 61, 42, 52, ... ]
```

My dilemma is because the type of `return $ b * 10 + a` seems to be different from the type of `[40 + a, 50 + a, 60 + a]`.

**Shouldn't the bind signature be like this?**

```
 (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

**In this example seems to be like**

```
[int] -> (int -> [int -> int -> int]) -> [int -> int]
```

**And**

```
[int] -> (int -> [int -> int]) -> [int]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s how it desugars and works operationally. You’re right that this:

```
do
  a <- [1, 2, 3]
  b <- [4, 5, 6]
  return $ a * 10 + b
```

Desugars to this:

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= \a -> 
  [4, 5, 6] >>= \b -> 
    return $ b * 10 + a
```

Which in turn is using the list instance of `Monad`, whose definitions of `>>=` and `return` (or `pure`) we can inline:

```
concatMap
  (\a -> concatMap
    (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
    [4, 5, 6])
  [1, 2, 3]
```

We can break apart `concatMap` into `concat` and `map`:

```
concat
  (map
    (\a -> concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6]))
    [1, 2, 3])
```

Now we can reduce this, and here I think is where you were encountering difficulty: reduction happens from the outside in, and doesn’t produce partially applied functions in this case; rather, it *captures* `a` in the closure of the inner lambda `(\b -> …)`. First, we map `(\a -> …)` over `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
concat
  [ (\a -> concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6])) 1
  , (\a -> concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6])) 2
  , (\a -> concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6])) 3
  ]

==

concat
  [ let a = 1
    in concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6])
  , let a = 2
    in concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6])
  , let a = 3
    in concat
      (map
        (\b -> [b * 10 + a])
        [4, 5, 6])
  ]
```

Then we can reduce the inner `map`s:

```
concat
  [ let a = 1
    in concat
      [ (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 4
      , (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 5
      , (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 6
      ]
  , let a = 2
    in concat
      [ (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 4
      , (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 5
      , (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 6
      ]
  , let a = 3
    in concat
      [ (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 4
      , (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 5
      , (\b -> [b * 10 + a]) 6
      ]
  ]

==

concat
  [ let a = 1
    in concat
      [ let b = 4 in [b * 10 + a]
      , let b = 5 in [b * 10 + a]
      , let b = 6 in [b * 10 + a]
      ]
  , let a = 2
    in concat
      [ let b = 4 in [b * 10 + a]
      , let b = 5 in [b * 10 + a]
      , let b = 6 in [b * 10 + a]
      ]
  , let a = 3
    in concat
      [ let b = 4 in [b * 10 + a]
      , let b = 5 in [b * 10 + a]
      , let b = 6 in [b * 10 + a]
      ]
  ]
```

Which we can then simplify by replacing variables with their values:

```
concat
  [ concat
    [ [4 * 10 + 1]
    , [5 * 10 + 1]
    , [6 * 10 + 1]
    ]
  , concat
    [ [4 * 10 + 2]
    , [5 * 10 + 2]
    , [6 * 10 + 2]
    ]
  , concat
    [ [4 * 10 + 3]
    , [5 * 10 + 3]
    , [6 * 10 + 3]
    ]
  ]
```

And reducing the calls to `concat`:

```
concat
  [ [ 4 * 10 + 1
    , 5 * 10 + 1
    , 6 * 10 + 1
    ]
  , [ 4 * 10 + 2
    , 5 * 10 + 2
    , 6 * 10 + 2
    ]
  , [ 4 * 10 + 3
    , 5 * 10 + 3
    , 6 * 10 + 3
    ]
  ]

==

[ 4 * 10 + 1
, 5 * 10 + 1
, 6 * 10 + 1
, 4 * 10 + 2
, 5 * 10 + 2
, 6 * 10 + 2
, 4 * 10 + 3
, 5 * 10 + 3
, 6 * 10 + 3
]
```

And of course the individual expressions:

```
[ 41, 51, 61
, 42, 52, 62
, 43, 53, 63
]
```

A case where you *will* see a list of partially applied functions is when using the `Applicative` instance of lists, for example, the equivalent to your code:

```
(\a b -> b * 10 + a) <$> [1, 2, 3] <*> [4, 5, 6]
```

The definition of `<$>`/`fmap` for lists is just `map`, so we partially apply the first argument of the lambda, producing a list of type `[Int -> Int]`, then `(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, here at type `[Int -> Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`, applies each function in its left operand to each value in its right operand.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason it's confusing is because you're working on this inside-out, by trying to think of the inner bind as producing a list of partially applied functions. It doesn't: `a` and `b` are closed over, not arguments waiting to be applied. Instead, start from the outside of the expression and work inwards:

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= \a -> (...)
```

For each item in the list, produce a list somehow, with access to `a` as a name for an item in the original list

```
... [4, 5, 6] >>= \b -> (...)
```

To produce the list needed by the previous step, produce a new list with access to both `a` and `b`, one from each of the two numbered lists.

```
... return $ b * 10 + a
```

To produce the list needed by the previous step, create a list of a single item, whose value is `b * 10 + a`.

You ask why the type of `return $ b * 10 + a` is different from the type of `[40 + a, 50 + a, 60 + a]`, but they're not: both are of type `[Int]`. Neither involves any functions. Rather, they both are lists of numbers, constructed by referring to already-closed-over variables. And indeed `(>>=)` has exactly the type that it should: it takes a list of int, and a function for producing a list of int from a single int, and gives back a different list of int:

```
(>>=) :: [Int] -> (Int -> [Int]) -> [Int]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `return x = [x]` and `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs` in the list monad. Thus

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= \a -> 
      ([4, 5, 6] >>= \b -> 
                 return $ b * 10 + a)
```

turns into

```
concatMap (\a -> (concatMap (\b -> [b*10+a]) [4,5,6])) [1,2,3]
```

which becomes (with `a` as a free variable in the function of `b`)

```
concatMap (\a -> [4*10+a, 5*10+a, 6*10+a]) [1,2,3]
```

There are no partially applied functions, just a single function that returns a list value using its argument 3 different times. This then reduces to

```
[4*10+1, 5*10+1, 6*10+1, 4*10+2, 5*10+2, 6*10+2, 4*10+3, 5*10+3, 6*10+3]
```

or

```
[41,51,61,42,52,62,43,53,63]
```